# How to write the dual problem (for stable matching)

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, lagrange-multiplier, duality-theorems, matching-theory

How do you write the dual of the following problem - I know the basics behind the Lagrangian function but I'm getting a little confused with how to handle the Lagrangian multipliers when we are dealing with two dimensions (i and j)?

Min $\sum_{i,j} x_{ij}$
Subject to \begin{align*}
\sum_j x_{ij} = 1 \forall i \\ 
\sum_i x_{ij} = 1 \forall j \\
x_{ij} + \sum_{k: w_k < w_j} x_{ik} + \sum_{l: m_l < m_i} x_{lj} \leq 1 \forall i,j \\ 
x_{ij} \geq 0 \forall i,j
\end{align*}

Comment: A really nice reference for duality is chapter 5 of Boyd and Vanderbergh. There's nothing special about having two indices, if you like, you can consider this is on index in the set $[n^2]$ instead of two in the set $[n]$.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I'll have a look. Do you mind elaborating or writing out a few steps to explain your last sentence? I was trying to write these constraints as matrices bu I am really confused about how to deal with the "forall i" and "for all j"

Comment: Maybe try writing out the case of $n = 2$.

Answer (score 0):

Arthur Benjamin's [S-O-B method](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2132755.pdf) is useful for obtaining the dual LP.  Here's your primal problem with the dual variables in parentheses:

\begin{align}
\text{minimize} \sum_{i,j} x_{ij} & \\ 
\sum_j x_{ij} &= 1 &&(\text{$\alpha_i$ free}) \\ 
\sum_i x_{ij} &= 1 &&(\text{$\beta_j$ free}) \\
x_{ij} + \sum_{k: w_k < w_j} x_{ik} + \sum_{l: m_l < m_i} x_{lj} &\leq 1 &&(\text{$\gamma_{ij} \le 0$}) \\ 
x_{ij} &\geq 0
\end{align}

The dual is then:
\begin{align}
\text{maximize} \sum_i \alpha_i + \sum_j \beta_j + \sum_{i,j} \gamma_{ij} & \\ 
\alpha_i + \beta_j + \gamma_{ij} + \sum_{k: w_k > w_j} \gamma_{ik} + \sum_{l: m_l > m_i} \gamma_{lj} &\le 1 &&(\text{$x_{ij}\ge 0$}) \\ 
\gamma_{ij} &\le 0
\end{align}